# struts2. Object fron jsp to action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

First of all I'm newbie in Struts.
I've a class:

```
public class Articulo {

private int codigo;
private String descripcion;

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}
public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

}
```

which is populated with values in a dispatcher. In the dispatcher I've

```
private Articulo articulo;
.......
public Articulo getArticulo() {
    return articulo;
}

public void setArticulo(Articulo articulo) {
    this.articulo = articulo;
}
```

There is also a JSP with

```
<s:property value="articulo"/>
```

which read ok the articulo. Also works articulo

```
<s:property value="articulo.codigo"/>
```

But now I want from that jsp forward the entire object articulo to another action.
I can do

```
<s:hidden name="articulo.codigo" value="%{articulo.codigo}"/>
<s:hidden name="articulo.descripcion" value="%{articulo.descripcion}"/>
```

and that works fine, but is there anyway to do something like

```
<s:hidden name="articulo" value="%{articulo}"/>
```

So, is there anyway to get the object from JSP without setting all the properties of it?

Comment: Have a look at chain result type. It is meant for maintaining variables states from one action to other... might help.

Comment: thanks bhatanant2! May be I'm wrong or don't understand correctly, but I think chain is for invoke an action from other action. http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/chain-result.html But I want action -> jsp -> action. Anyway, thanks again. Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 points:

1. Problem: you can't transfer object using `<s:hidden />`, all the parameter, what are transfered with HTTP should be string. Since you cannot convert this object to String, you can't transfer it using HTTP either.
2. Solution: You can put your object into session, so that you can access it anytime you want. here is an [EXAMPLE](http://www.java4s.com/struts-tutorials/example-on-struts-2-sessionaware-interface/)

Comment: thanks Jaiwo99! I thought about session, but I want to believe there is someway. I read something about StrutsTypeConverter, but I don't understand at all. Maybe session is The answer. Thanks again! jon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can transfer object in two ways either by parameter or store it in session and access it whenever you need it.

```
<jsp:forward page="URL" >
  <jsp:param name="ParamName1" value="YourObject" />
</jsp:forward>
```

Visit here for more detail.
http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/actions/forward

Comment: thanks Fenil! I think jsp:forward is to use like JSP -> JSP and I need JSP -> Action -> JSP. So maybe the best way is the session.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the object information in sessions is usually the preferred method.

But an alternative option is to create your own [Type Converter](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CreatingaTypeConverter).

> Create a type converter by extending StrutsTypeConverter. The
>   Converter's role is to convert a String to an Object and an Object to
>   a String.

By doing so, you could so something like `<s:hidden name="articulo" value="%{articulo}"/>`

Keep in mind **this method is insecure** as the object values will be printed out as String in the hidden tag and can be seen through the browser.

But the advantage is that this method works across different sessions if you have a need for such a thing.